# How can I come from NOT x AND y OR NOT z to two formulas: NOT x OR NOT z and NOT y OR z

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I dont understand how I come from

```
NOT x AND y OR NOT z
```

to two formulas:

```
NOT x OR NOT z
NOT y OR z
```

Can somebody show me the rule? It should bring the first formula into CNF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to have parentheses:

$$(\neg X \land Y) \lor \neg Z \Leftrightarrow (\neg X \lor \neg Z) \land (Y \lor \neg Z)$$

by the rule of (right-) Distribution

And yes, it is now in CNF.